# How to validate Google Token ID sent from Android on Ruby on Rails server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, ruby-on-rails-5, google-oauth

I have an android app with Google sign-in. As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth), I generated a token ID:

```java
// Configure Google Sign-In with the requestIdToken

GoogleSignInOptions googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

// Handle result

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
        String tokenId = account.getIdToken();
    }
}
```

I'm facing the problem on the server side, with Ruby on Rails. I'm trying to use [google-id-token](https://github.com/google/google-id-token) gem. The README gives the following example:

```rb
validator = GoogleIDToken::Validator.new(expiry: 1800)
begin
  payload = validator.check(token, required_audience, required_client_id)
  email = payload['email']
rescue GoogleIDToken::ValidationError => e
  report "Cannot validate: #{e}"
end
```

I have the `token` (from the android java code). What is `required_audience`? Should I use the same `client_id` of my client app? When I try to run the code on server, I'm getting payload as `nil`.

Also, I would like to know if this is the right way to verify the token ID.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research, I found answers to my own questions. Here are they:

**What is required_audience?**

It can be obtained from decoded JWT string. You can decode it as follows:

```rb
JWT.decode(token, nil, false)
```

**Should I use the same client_id of my client app?**

Yes. The `required_audience` and `required_client_id` should be same. Otherwise, verification fails

**Then why was I getting payload as `nil`?**

The problem is, the [gem in GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-id-token) and the one in RubyGems are different. I solved this problem by pointing Gemfile gem to GitHub:

```rb
gem 'google-id-token', git: 'https://github.com/google/google-id-token.git'
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I still get `Token not verified as issued by Google` or `nil` respectively – even with my firebase project id for audience AND client id as well as with the gem from github. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: No, I didn't try the google-id-token gem yet. Will try that, thanks.

Comment: required_audience is not the entire JWT token, but the 'aud' key inside the decoded token. So to clarify:
  
  required_audience = JWT.decode(token, nil, false)[0]['aud']